# ¿Como puedo hacer un boton que actualice una parte de otro useState?

Tags: api, react-native

estoy programando en ReactNative y estoy utilizando la pokeApi.
Quiero hacer un boton el cual actualice el useState que me trae la info del a api.
A continuación el codigo:

```
      const [poke, setPoke] = useState([]);
const [nextPage, setNextPage] = useState(0);
useEffect(()=>setLoadPoke(`https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon?offset=${nextPage}&limit=10`),[nextPage]);
const [loadPoke, setLoadPoke] = useState(
    `https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon?offset=${nextPage}&limit=10`,
);

const getpoke = async () => {
    const res = await fetch(loadPoke);
    const data = await res.json();
    setLoadPoke(data.next);

    function crearObjetoPokemon(result) {
        result.forEach(async (pokemon) => {
            const res = await fetch(`https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/${pokemon.name}`);
            const data = await res.json();
            setPoke((currentList) => [
                ...currentList,
            data
            ]);
        });
    }
    crearObjetoPokemon(data.results);
};
useEffect(() => {
    getpoke();
}, []);
```

Ahora el boton:

```
                <Button title="Siguiente"
            onPress={ () => setNextPage( nextPage + 10 ) }/>
```

Si bien actualiza la const de nextPage, no actualiza la de loadPoke... Alguna solucion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ya te había comentado en otra publicación, pero quizá no fue suficiente información.

con el siguiente código tu aplicación ya debería funcionar perfectamente:

```js
const [poke, setPoke] = useState([]);
const [ offset, setOffset ] = useState(0);

const consultarApi = async ()=>{
  const url = `https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon?offset=${offset}&limit=10`;
  const res = await fetch(url);
  const data = await res.json();
  setPoke(data.results);
}

useEffect(()=>{
  consultarApi();
},[offset])

const paginaSiguiente = ()=>{
  setOffset(offset + 10)
}
const paginaAnterior = ()=>{
  if (offset === 0) return;
  setOffset(offset - 10)
}
```

recuerda que useEffect recibe un arreglo de dependencias y si agregas una, cuando esta cambie el efecto se ejecutara de nuevo, por esta razón solo se agrega offset como dependencia y cuando lo actualices (ya sea sumando o restando) react se encargara de ejecutarlo de nuevo obteniendo los datos actualizados basados en el endpoint url que cambia cada vez que actualizas el offset.

en mi caso, yo declaro el endpoint en una constante url dentro de la función que hará el fetch no veo la necesidad de agregarlo en un estado.

Y si lo que quieres es obtener toda la información del pokemon, haría otro fetch, tomando en cuenta que react esta basado en componentes si tienes algo así:

```js
const App = ()=>{
 //estado y funciones para obtener el listado de pokemons (o pokemones) aqui.
return (
  <div>
  {poke.map((pokemon)=>{
    return (
      <PokemonInfo pokemon={pokemon} />
    )
  })}
  <div>
)
}
export default App;
```

haria el fetch de la informacion de cada pokemon asi:

```js
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

const PokemonInfo = ({ pokemon }) => {
  const [pokemonInfo, setPokemonInfo] = useState({});

  useEffect(() => {
    const obtenerInformacionPoke = async () => {
      const url = `https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/${pokemon.name}`;
      const res = await fetch(url);
      const data = await res.json();
      setPokemonInfo(data);
    };
    obtenerInformacionPoke();
  }, [pokemon]);

  if (pokemon.name === "") {
    return null;
  }

  return (
    <>
      <p>Name: {pokemon.name}</p>
      <p>base_experience: {pokemonInfo.base_experience}</p>
    </>
  );
};

export default PokemonInfo;
```

puedes ver un ejemplo acá https://codesandbox.io/s/react-lista-con-paginacion-7r4ne
haciendo los cambios respectivos debe funcionar en React Native.

**pd: para el que dijo que el await en el res.json() era innecesario, si quito el await simplemente no obtengo la información formateada en json.**

a menos que no utilices async / await y utilices .then()

```js
fetch(url).then(res=> res.json).then(data => setPoke(data))
```

pero en mi caso creo que es mucho mas legible async / await.

Comment: en este caso utilice div y p porque mientras escribía el código olvide que estas utilizando react native, pero el código funciona igual, solo debes cambiar los componentes / etiquetas  utilizados/as

Comment: Buenas Ronald!
Tu codigo me funciona pero a la hora de imprimir las cosas en PokemonInfo.js no las imprime, sin embargo reconoce que le paso datos...
¿Tendre que usar una FlatList o se puede evitar? Si se puede contactarte por algun otro medio para tener una comunicación buena decime, por que creo que tengo muchas preguntas :')

Comment: Que extraño me reconoce todo, osea acepta los datos que recibe pero se niega a imprimirlos jaja

Comment: @Mankusa en react native yo utilizaria un activity indicator con un estado de loading en true y haría la comprobación {loading ? (<ActivityIndicator size='large' />): (<View>...Toda la información aquí.</View>)} y con un setTimeout  luego de setPokemonInfo utilizaría  setTimeout(()=>{setLoading(false)},3000) //en este caso son 3 segundos pero puedes ajustarlo a tu conveniencia

Comment: yo tuve exactamente ese mismo problema con una app que estoy desarrollando y con eso lo solucione. intentaba leer informacion de un arreglo dentro del objeto pero como al principio era undefined marca error con un estado de loading y verificando si loading es true retorno un activity indicator y si es false toda la interfaz

Comment: Mañana lo aplicare y te dire que onda, gracias! :)

Comment: puedes revisar el siguiente codigo https://codesandbox.io/s/react-lista-con-paginacion-7r4ne?file=/src/App.js lo actualice y utilizo un estado loading mucho mas legible que los ternarios del código que comente acá. solo utilizo un string 'cargando' pero en react native puedes utilizar el ActivityIndicator y queda perfecto.

Comment: AAAAAAAAAAAAAAH YA ENTIENDO LO QUE APLICAS, sos un genio.
Gracias hermano!

Answer (score 0):

El parámetro que recibe useState es el state por default. No va a "reaccionar" a los cambios de estado de "nextPage".
Para que reaccione deberías hacer algo así:

```
const[nextPage,setNextPage] = useState(0);
const [loadPoke, setLoadPoke] = useState(
    `https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon?offset=0&limit=10`,
);

useEffect(()=>setLoadPoke(`https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon?offset=${nextPage}&limit=10`),[nextPage]);
```

De todas maneras, tené en cuenta que "loadPoke" va a cambiar cada vez que cambie "nextPage".

---

EDIT:

Con el código completo, analizandoló, veo que:

1. "la url de destino de la próxima petición" se setea en 3 lugares distintos:

- al cambiar de página (al hacer click en el link)
- al hacer el fetch de poke (que por lo visto, lo hace una única vez al renderizar). Esto lo hace con el data.next.
- Como state inicial, en donde lo "inicializás" en 0.

El del state inicial no cumple ninguna función, ya que "se pisa" con el contenido que venga en "data.next". Por ende, ese podés ponerlo vacío (en tu código).

Ergo, te quedaría así:

```
const [poke, setPoke] = useState([]);
const [nextPage, setNextPage] = useState(0);
const [loadPoke, setLoadPoke] = useState();

const getpoke = async () => {
    const res = await fetch(loadPoke);
    const data = res.json();
    setLoadPoke(data.next);

    function crearObjetoPokemon(result) {
        result.forEach(async (pokemon) => {
            const res = await fetch(`https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/${pokemon.name}`);
            const data = await res.json();
            setPoke((currentList) => [
                ...currentList,
            data
            ]);
        });
    }
    crearObjetoPokemon(data.results);
};

useEffect(() => {
    getpoke();
}, []);

useEffect(()=>
setLoadPoke(`https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon?offset=${nextPage}&limit=10`),
[nextPage]);
```

---

Algo de lo que te puede estar pasando es que al hacer click en el "nextPage", este componente se vuelva a renderizar (de 0) y entre al "getPoke" de vuelta, volviendo a generar lo mismo una y otra vez.

Igual el código es un poco confuso, quizás ayudaría mejor entender que trae el "data" de getPoke. Quizás, con más data, te pueda ayudar a simplificarlo.

Comment: No me funciona, eso lo habia intentado antes... Subo el codigo completo para que puedas leer mas a ver si encontras algun fallo, yo todavia no logro entender que fallo puedo llegar a tener :'(

Comment: Tu código está mal. El parámetro del "useState" no va a reaccionar con los cambios de estado de "nextPage".

Agregá el useEffect que te pasé (sin pisar el otro). Ahí te actualizo.

Comment: Intente sin pisarlo pero sin duda sigue dando error, tal vez influencia bastante que mi codigo este muy mal o mal. Lo hice asi para poder poner la imagen de los pokemons en la misma screen ya que no me las traia directamente

Comment: Perdón, estaba con trabajo. 

1) const data = await res.json();
Eso está mal. res.json() es sincrónico, no necesita que lo hagas con await.

2) Tenés un problema que el "setLoadPoke" lo hacés en 2 instancias distintas: o bien cuando cambia de página, o bien cuando hace el getPoke. Yo lo haría de la forma en la cual te voy a escribir.

Comment: Buenas! Profe de la forma que me pasaste y no trae nada ;(.
El data lo que trae es el primer url puesto es decir:https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon?offset=${nextPage}&limit=10
El cual el valor predeterminado del nextpage es = 0.
El error que aparece con el codigo que propones es "Possible unhandled promise rejection".
Entiendo tu explicación, gracais por la corrección :)

Comment: El possible unhandled promise rejection es porque tenés que trycatchear el resultado del await.

Comment: Ahi le puse el try catch y no imprime, sinceramente no se.
Que cosa extraña-